# Alternative zend core function in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, zend-framework

I want to call the "getlist-options" template with the controller.
In the zend-framework, I was able to do this with

```
$this->action()
```

What an alternative function is in laravel. And does it just exist?

Comment: What is `getlist-options`? is it an object in your application or is it something built in Zend?

Comment: @CaddyDZ It's a my html template which has included in main layout;

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to mark this question as answered (I recommend reading the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs))
Here's the equivalent in Laravel to return an html template named `getlist-options.blade.php`

```php
return view('layouts.getlist-options');
```

Assuming the template file is in the `resources/views/layouts` directory